# Prove the maximum value of entropy function

Tags: probability, summation, solution-verification, information-theory, entropy

I'm writing a paper on Information Theory and I can't get my head around this task:

I'd like to prove that the maximum value of the [Shannon entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) $H$ is reached when  each event in the set of probabilities $Ps=\{P(x_1), P(x_2), ..., P(x_n)\}$ has the same value.

The $H$ function is defined like this:

$$  H(S)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{card(S)}P(x_i)*(-\log_2(P(x_i)))  $$

I could only prove this with $card(S)<=2$ but could not find any technique to do it for $card(S) = N$.

I think that a possible solution would be solving it with a proof by induction using $card(S)$ (the length of $S$) as our parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but perhaps one of the easiest is via [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Let $n$ indicate the cardinality of $S$. Then, write
$$
\begin{align}
H(S) & = \sum_x p(x) (-\log p(x)) \\
& = \sum_x p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)}\\
& \le \log \sum_x p(x) \frac{1}{p(x)}\\
& =\log n
\end{align}
$$
The inequality uses Jensen's inequality and that $\log$ is a concave function. It is easy to check that the uniform distribution, $p(x)=1/n$ for all $x$, achieves this upper bound.

Comment: Doesn't Jensen's inequality only works for $card(S)=2$ ?

Comment: By $card(S)$, do you just mean the number of outcomes of the random variable $S$? Then, no, Jensen's inequality holds for any $S$ of any finite or infinite cardinality.

Comment: No, i mean the lenght of S

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by the "length of $S$", or perhaps your question at all. I think you need to clarify your question. What is the outcome space of the random variable whose entropy you are trying to compute?

Comment: S is a set of events with random probability of happening, the sum of the probability of every event is 100% (1) and I know that the maximum value of the H function is reached when every probability is the same, so  when $P(x_1) = P(x_2) = ... = P(x_n)$ the thing is that i don't know how to prove it

Comment: OK, then I think we are talking about the same thing. As I mentioned, Jensen's inequality works for any $n$.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form (in my answer, I use that $\log$ is concave)